# Error when trying to debug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I try to run "Start Debugging" I get the error:

"Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web server. Unable to start debugging. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040d10. [OK]"

Click "OK".

Again I run "Start Debugging"... but now opens "ASP.NET Development Server - Port 1809" but now I get the error:

"Unable to attach to application 'WebDev.WebServer20.EXE' (PID: 6592) usign 'GUSTAVO-PC'. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040d10. Do you want to continue anyway? [YES | NO]

Anybody have similar issues?

Running on Windows 7 x64.
Running Visual Studio 2012 Professional Versión 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 as Administrator.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? That looks like the .NET 2.0 web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your system is having trouble loading the process image into memory. This is probably due to a corrupted registry file somewhere in the load chain. I doubt it is a problem with the executable. I once had a similar problem which I resolved simply by running a repair installation - no worries since :)

Comment: Now works. Repair Visual Studio did not solve the problem. I had to uninstall Visual Studio and then re-install Visual Studio and updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this very problem after applying an URL Rewrite rule to redirect the traffic from http to https as per this solution:

[Https redirection in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961050/iis-8-5-url-rewrite-force-redirect-http-https-for-non-www)

This is causing an error because my solution is configured with a local iis with a startup project url.

What seems to happen in this case is that the project url cannot be resolved in iis 7.5 because the https binding is not on the host name but rather on a blank hostname.

[image: Iis bindings configuration]

The other way to diagnose this, is if you go into your projects properties, web tab, and try to change the project url to https instead of http. You will get this message as if your setup was wrong inside iis (but in fact its working and iss is serving the link).

> The local IIS URL https://xxxx.com/ specified for Web project xxxx has
>   not been configured. To keep these settings you need to configure the
>   virtual directory. Would you like to create the virtual directory now?

What I ended up doing, is exclude the https redirect rule to be applied in the local development url.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^local.development.com" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: based on this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219744
I used this: 
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />

Answer (score -1):

I had also this problem when I tried to change the language.

When I put the default language, the error disappeared.