# IIS Rewrite rule - ignore for localhost

Tags: regex, iis, isapi-rewrite

I have the following rule which is working well for redirecting my www requests to the root.

However I can't seem to turn it off for localhost. Here is what I have now:

```
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

I've tried many things including things like:

```
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Could you help? Regexes are my weakness alas

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947827/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried adding a condition <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" /> but that didnt work? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">`?

Comment: No it doesnt work unfortunately...

Comment: Try using a _URL Validator_ without _localhost_. `^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$` Then it won't match `localhost`.

Comment: Have you tried just `localhost` as your pattern

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219744/iis-url-rewrite-https-rule-ignoring-localhost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS URL Rewrite https rule ignoring localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219744/iis-url-rewrite-https-rule-ignoring-localhost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a condition to only match requests that start with `www.` instead of trying to negate when you don't want the rule to apply? This avoids the need to negate `localhost` because `localhost` never matches in the conditions:

```
<rule name="Strip WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{URL}" />
</rule>
```

However, your example of the rule you tried (your second code block) also works for me in testing with IIS on a Windows 10 VM. I can browse to `localhost` without a redirect. Perhaps there is another issue here.

Comment: The pattern should be `pattern="^www\.(.*)"`, escape the dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good catch, without the additional \ it matches any character after www so if your domain happened to be wwwfoo.com it would try to redirect to oo.com. I corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would not mix the rules of different hosting environments; localhost (for local development) and www, your live environment.
If you keep them separate, you don't have to enable and disable rules depending on the environment.

The `rules` section has a `configSource` attribute via which you can point to an other separate file, eg. `RewriteRules.config`.
Doing so, `web.config` will look like here below.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Other settings go here. -->

    <system.webServer>
        <!-- other settings go here --->

        <rewrite>
            <rules configSource="RewriteRules.config">
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>   
</configuration>
```

The `RewriteRules.config` file contains the rules.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
        <!-- Rule details go here -->
    </rule>
</rules>
```

You make a separte version of this `RewriteRules.config`file per environment, containing only the appropriate rules and deploy it to the concerned webserver.

This has many benefits.

- Only the rules for the concerned environment are being evaluated, which is better for performance.
- It is more flexible if you have other environments like QA (http://qa. ...) and dev (http://dev. ...).
- You don't have to worry (and test) whether the rules of one environment will interfere with the ones of an other one, here: local vs live.

The deployment of the `RewriteRules.config` file can be included in a deployment automation.