# IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite force redirect http --> https for non www

Tags: redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting

I am starting with the rewrite module have a problem with a "simple" IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite redirect http --> https for a non www site.

Problem: If the domain matches the action url parameter i always get "http://" and not "https://".

This is my rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I can't post several links so "domain" = crm.test.com. The site with the rewrite rule is bound to "domain"=crm.test.com on port 2080.

I want to redirect "http://" to "http**s**://", but i always get "http://" as location in response:

```
   HTTP/1.1·302·Redirect
   Connection:·close
   Content-Length:·176
   Date:·Thu,·15·Jan·2015·08:21:21·GMT
   Location:·http://domain/                      <--
   Content-Type:·text/html;·charset=UTF-8
   Server:·Microsoft-IIS/8.5
   X-Powered-By:·ASP.NET
```

I tried the following action url parameter:

Not working:

```
"https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" -> http://domain/
"https://domain/{R:1}" -> http://domain/
"https://{HTTP_HOST}:443/{R:1}" -> http://domain/
"https://{HTTP_HOST}/1" -> http://domain/1/
```

Working:

```
"https1://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" -> https1://domain/
"https://{HTTP_HOST}:444/{R:1}" -> https://domain:444/
"https://test.domain.com/{R:1}" -> https://test.domain.com/
"https://www.google.com/{R:1}" -> https://www.google.com/
```

I found "[URL Rewrite on IIS from http to https is not working,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028223/url-rewrite-on-iis-from-http-to-https-is-not-working)", but this doesn't solve my problem.

Did i missed something?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for us:

```
            <rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Sorry, same result with this configuration. Thanks Martin

Comment: Are you adding this to global rules or per web site rules?
If 
   "https://{HTTP_HOST}:443/{R:1}" -> http://domain/ 
does not work, but 
   "https://{HTTP_HOST}:444/{R:1}" -> https://domain:444/ 
does, then maybe you have another rule higher up the chain that is preventing this rule being hit?

Comment: This is a local rule and it's the only rule i got. I set up an aspx webpage to try to redirect from here and found that all links on the page are automatically changed from http to https if the links contain the requestet host. This seems the problem, maybe it is not the rewrite module. Thanks Martin

Answer (score 2):

O. k., i found the solution - the link translation is caused by a tmg 2010 in front of the iis. The tmg has a bug where the link translation resets the https links to http in case of a 301. Problem an solution are described here:

http://blog.sanibellogic.com/2008/09/default

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924373

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can also config the redirect domain with or without www using URL rewrite. The SSL cert only include: www FQDN.

web.config example (domain example is: sysadmit.com):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <clear />
       <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sysadmit.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/05/windows-iis-redirigir-http-https.html